# How do bare-metal/hosted hypervisors relate to hardware and software virtualization?

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

Do I understand it properly that **Hardware Virtualization** is basically a system with a **bare-metal hypervisor** and **Software Virtualization** is a system with **hosted hypervisor**?

(And, therefore, because hosted hypervisor can't use Ring 0 access privileges it needs all those tricks like **Binary Translation** and **Paravirtualization**)

If it's not true, how do bare-metal/hosted hypervisors relate to hardware and software virtualization?

[image: scheme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where these terms were coming from: http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/VMware_paravirtualization.pdf.

> With x86 computer virtualization, a virtualization layer is added
>   between the hardware and operating system

So, my guess was valid. By **Hardware Virtualization** they did mean **virtualization with type-1 (== hardware-based, bare-metal) hypervisor**.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware assisted virtualization is a feature of the CPU.  It helps software to do virtualization. Software such as Xen, KVM, VMWare etc.

In the case of Amazon (unless it's changed recently?) they use a customized version of the Xen hypervisor. Xen supports both [paravirtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization) (linux) and [hvm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-assisted_virtualization) (linux/windows) guest images.

HVM requires Intel Virtualization Extensions. PV doesn't (or didn't in the past).

With Amazon (and others) you're presented with a virtual machine (guest) that is either a paravirtual guest or a pretend and complete virtual machine that emulates the BIOS etc we well.

Some hypervisors allow another hypervisor to run as a guest.  If I'm not wrong I think xen has supported this.  I'm not sure if it's a good idea personally.

Does that answer your question?

---

one last go.

"Software Virtualization"? can you please share a link to that term.  Not seen it before.  Virtualization software on the other hand is mentioned widely.

One such type of virtualization software is called a hypervisor.  And to steal a quote from wikipedia

> A hypervisor or virtual machine monitor (VMM) is a piece of computer
>   software, firmware or hardware that creates and runs virtual machines.
>   A computer on which a hypervisor is running one or more virtual
>   machines is defined as a host machine. Each virtual machine is called
>   a guest machine.

The host of course is a bare metal server.

Comment: Please update your question and clarify what you're asking.